# How to use the lib library compiled by vc++ in gcc? Or how does cgo use vc++?

Tags: c++, c, go, visual-c++, mingw-w64

I want to use the com interface of windows in go, but I encountered an annoying problem. The error message is as follows:

```sh
$ gcc main.c -L. -lfileselector -o main
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ./fileselector.dll when searching for -lfileselector
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ./fileselector.dll when searching for -lfileselector
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfileselector
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I learned from other people's posts on stackoverflow that this may be a library compiled by vc++, which is not compatible with gcc. My library is indeed compiled with vc++ due to the com interface of windows.

Can CGO of GO language replace the original GCC with VC++ as the compiler?

Is there any way to make VC++ and GCC libraries compatible?

Or, can you call the com interface of windows through the API of MinGW?

Part of the code of the library is as follows:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>

const char *save_file_dialog() {
    const char *filePathString = "";

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return filePathString;
    IFileSaveDialog *fileSave;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileSaveDialog, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileSaveDialog, (void **) &fileSave);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        fileSave->SetFileTypes(sizeof(fileTypes) / sizeof(COMDLG_FILTERSPEC), fileTypes);
        fileSave->SetFileTypeIndex(2);
        fileSave->Show(nullptr);
        IShellItem *item;
        hr = fileSave->GetResult(&item);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            PWSTR filePath;
            hr = item->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &filePath);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && filePath) {
                filePathString = unicode_to_utf8(filePath);
                if (have_suffix(filePathString) == -1) {
                    UINT fileType{};
                    fileSave->GetFileTypeIndex(&fileType);
                    filePathString = (char *) append_suffix(filePathString, fileType);
                }
            }
            item->Release();
        }
        fileSave->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return filePathString;
    } else {
        return filePathString;
    }
}
```

Its function is to open a file dialog box through the IFileSaveDialog of the windows com interface.

Comment: The libraries between gcc and VS are not interchangeable. But you can use WinAPI in MinGW, that's what it's for. I don't think COM should be a problem. I see output about DLLs. Dlls are different than libraries, you can access the DLL functions.

Comment: The duplicate applies for both directions.

Comment: But this code of mine failed to compile in MinGW, the reason is IID_IFileOpenDialog, gcc error:
error:'IID_IFileOpenDialog' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Try adding `#include <ShObjIdl_core.h>`